# Split and Join element in array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a process mapping and splitting like this:

```js
    var input = [{Sensor:"DHT11", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:00:00", Data:"Humidity: 60.1, Temperature: 30.2"},
    {Sensor:"Piezo", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:00:10", Data:"Vibration level: 10"},
    {Sensor:"PEM-004T", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:00:20", Data:"Voltage: 220.3, Current: 0.13"},
    {Sensor:"DHT11", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:01:00", Data:"Humidity: 60.2, Temperature: 30.0"},
    {Sensor:"Piezo", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:01:10", Data:"Vibration level: 20"},
    {Sensor:"PEM-004T", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:01:20", Data:"Voltage: 220.5, Current: 0.16"}
    ]
    
    const convert = (input) =>
    Object.entries(
      input
        .flatMap(({ Data, Time }) =>
          Data.split(", ").map((x, i) => ({
            data: x,
            time: Time,
          }))
        )
    )
    
    console.log(convert(input))
```

And now I want to split the `Data` key's values on the comma separator producing a new entry which on itself will be split on a new key/value pair, while keeping the timestamp association for each resulting entry:

```
[
  [ '0', { name: 'Humidity', data: 60.1', time: '11:00:00' } ],
  [ '1', { name: 'Temperature', data: 30.2', time: '11:00:00' } ],
  [ '2', { name: 'Vibration level', data: 10', time: '11:00:10' } ],
  [ '3', { name: 'Voltage', data: 220.3', time: '11:00:20' } ],
  [ '4', { name: 'Current', data: 0.13', time: '11:00:20' } ],
  [ '5', { name: 'Humidity', data: 60.2', time: '11:01:00' } ],
  [ '6', { name: 'Temperature', data: 30.0', time: '11:01:00' } ],
  [ '7', { name: 'Vibration level', data: 20', time: '11:01:10' } ],
  [ '8', { name: 'Voltage', data: 220.5', time: '11:01:20' } ],
  [ '9', { name: 'Current', data: 0.16', time: '11:01:20' } ]
]
```

How could I achieve this functionally?

Comment: And the problem is? All you need to know is already in your question.

Comment: If you don't use a short arrow function, you can easily add statements before constructing the new object: `x => { /* ... commands here ... */  return { name: ..., ... }; }`

Comment: I want to split the first result to the final result as I posted

Answer (score 1):

you need to split your 'x' data into the desired values

```js
var input = [{Sensor:"DHT11", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:00:00", Data:"Humidity: 60.1, Temperature: 30.2"},
    {Sensor:"Piezo", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:00:10", Data:"Vibration level: 10"},
    {Sensor:"PEM-004T", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:00:20", Data:"Voltage: 220.3, Current: 0.13"},
    {Sensor:"DHT11", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:01:00", Data:"Humidity: 60.2, Temperature: 30.0"},
    {Sensor:"Piezo", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:01:10", Data:"Vibration level: 20"},
    {Sensor:"PEM-004T", Date:"28/05/2021", Time:"11:01:20", Data:"Voltage: 220.5, Current: 0.16"}
    ]
    
const convert = (input) =>
  Object.entries(
    input.flatMap(({ Data, Time }) =>
      Data.split(", ").map((x, i) => {
          const [nameval,dataval] = x.split(':');
        return {
          name: nameval,
          data:dataval,
          time: Time,
        };
      })
    )
  );
    
    console.log(convert(input))
```

Answer (score 0):

You were basically there. Just a little adjustment in the last `map()` and a `Number` conversion on the data

```js
var input = [{
    Sensor: "DHT11",
    Date: "28/05/2021",
    Time: "11:00:00",
    Data: "Humidity: 60.1, Temperature: 30.2"
  },
  {
    Sensor: "Piezo",
    Date: "28/05/2021",
    Time: "11:00:10",
    Data: "Vibration level: 10"
  },
  {
    Sensor: "PEM-004T",
    Date: "28/05/2021",
    Time: "11:00:20",
    Data: "Voltage: 220.3, Current: 0.13"
  },
  {
    Sensor: "DHT11",
    Date: "28/05/2021",
    Time: "11:01:00",
    Data: "Humidity: 60.2, Temperature: 30.0"
  },
  {
    Sensor: "Piezo",
    Date: "28/05/2021",
    Time: "11:01:10",
    Data: "Vibration level: 20"
  },
  {
    Sensor: "PEM-004T",
    Date: "28/05/2021",
    Time: "11:01:20",
    Data: "Voltage: 220.5, Current: 0.16"
  }
]

const convert = (input) =>
  Object.entries(
    input
    .flatMap(({
        Data,
        Time
      }) =>
      Data.split(", ").map((x, i) => {
        x = x.split(":");

        return {
          name: x[0],
          data: Number(x[1]),
          time: Time,
        }
      })
    )
  )

console.log(convert(input))
```